# How to put hover css for individual image in a list?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am working on a website. It needs to show six images in one page. Three are in one block. Below is my html code for this.

```
 <html>
<body>
    <div class="capabilities clearfix">
      <ul class="large-block-grid-3 medium-block-grid-2 small-block-grid-1 cap">

        <li>

            <a href="#"><img src="images/capalibities.png"></a>

                <span class="text"><span>
                    <div class="head text-center"></div>
                    <div class="subhead text-center"></div>
                </span></span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/capalibities.png"></a>
                <span class="text"><span>
                    <div class="head text-left">Creative</div>
                    <div class="subhead text-left"></div>
                </span></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/capalibities.png"></a>
                <span class="text"><span>
                    <div class="head text-left">Design</div>
                    <div class="subhead text-left"></div>
                </span></span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/capalibities.png"></a>
                <span class="text"><span>
                    <div class="head text-left">Technology</div>
                    <div class="subhead text-left"></div>
                </span></span>


        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/capalibities.png"></a>
                <span class="text"><span>
                    <div class="head text-left">Social</div>
                    <div class="subhead text-left"></div>
                </span></span>


        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/capalibities.png"></a>
                            <span class="text"><span>
                    <div class="head text-left">Media Buying</div>
                    <div class="subhead text-left"></div>
                </span></span>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Here, I need to show the text content and #00003b this color when I hover the images in the list. 


    span.text {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;

    }

    span.text span {
      display: block;


    }
    span.text {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200%;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 900ms;
      -moz-transition: opacity 900ms;
      -o-transition: opacity 900ms;
      transition: opacity 900ms;

    }

    ul.cap li:hover span.text {
      opacity: 0.85;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient( left, #002a67, #0079dd) !important; /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #002a67, #0079dd) !important; /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #002a67, #0079dd) !important; /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #002a67, #0079dd) !important; /* Standard syntax */

    }


    .head{
        font-family: "museo_sans900";
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 40px;
        line-height: 1;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        margin: 54% 7% 0% 5%;
      text-transform: uppercase;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-30px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(-30px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(-30px);
    transform: translateZ(-30px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s, transform 0.2s 0.2s;
    }

    .subhead{
      margin: 0% 7% 0% 5%;
    }
```

If I use this css, the hover comes for the whole page instead of coming for the individual box. Is position the reason for this to happen?

Comment: Can you create a working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your snippet the hover overlay is an absolute position and is positioned relative to the first parent element in case this none so it will contain the block  which will display on the whole page.

In-order to fix your issue copy this :

```
.capabilities ul li {
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a fiddle for this one, then its nice,

There is some span is closing, but no opening tags, `</span></span>`

Also what you mean by text content. Hope you need to show the contents of

```
                <span class="text"><span>
                <div class="head text-left">Creative</div>
                <div class="subhead text-left"></div>
```

on mouse over. Try to use `float`. am not sure, because your question not fully understandable.